# How is channel terminated if Hangup() is not specified in Asterisk?

Tags: asterisk

Consider the following example in asterisk/extensions.conf:

```
exten => 1,1,AGI(my)
exten => 2,1,Answer()
same => n,Playback(tt-weasels)
same => n,Hangup()
```

Is it necessary to specify Hangup() after AGI()?

How will the situation change if this extensions.conf is used instead? (differs with previous only that `Answer()` is used)

```
exten => 1,1,Answer()
same => n,AGI(my)
exten => 2,1,Answer()
same => n,Playback(tt-weasels)
same => n,Hangup()
```

For completeness, here is the agi script:

```
#!/bin/sh
read; while [ "$REPLY" ]; do read; done
some-command
echo SET VARIABLE AGISTATUS SUCCESS; read
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from extensions.conf.sample

```
; If autofallthrough is set, then if an extension runs out of
; things to do, it will terminate the call with BUSY, CONGESTION
; or HANGUP depending on Asterisk's best guess. This is the default.
;
; If autofallthrough is not set, then if an extension runs out of
; things to do, Asterisk will wait for a new extension to be dialed
; (this is the original behavior of Asterisk 1.0 and earlier).
;

;autofallthrough=no
```